# Definition of $\mathfrak{g}$-differential graded algebra

Tags: lie-algebras, differential-algebra, graded-algebras, differential-graded-algebras

I am reading Group actions on manifolds by Eckhard Meinrenken ([Lecture Notes, University of Toronto, Spring 2003](http://www.math.toronto.edu/mein/teaching/LectureNotes/action.pdf)).

In page $45$, definition $5.2$, author introduce the notion of $\mathfrak{g}$-differential graded algebra. Here $\mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie algebra ( I am thinking it is Lie algebra of Lie group $G$ but not sure)

> A differential graded algebra is an graded algebra $A = 
>  \bigoplus_{I=0}^{\infty}A_i$ with a differential $d$ of degree $1$,
>   such  that $d$ is a derivation. It is called a
>   $\mathfrak{g}$-differential algebra if, in addition, there are
>   derivations $L_X$  of degree $0$ and $i_X$  of degree $-1$ for all
>   $X\in \mathfrak{g}$, satisfying the relations of contractions, Lie 
>   derivative and differential on a manifold with a
>   $\mathfrak{g}$-action:
>
> 1. $[i_{X}, i_{Y}] = 0$
> 2. $[L_X,i_{Y}] = i_{[X,Y]}$
> 3. $[d, L_\xi] = 0$
> 4. $[L_X,L_Y] = L_{[X,Y]}$
> 5. $[d, d] = 0$
> 6. $[d,i_X] = L_X$

I don’t understand the notation of $[d,d]=0$, what Lie algebra structure are we fixing here? The same confusion for all other conditions. Is this the standard way to define a$\mathfrak{g}$-differential graded algebra?

Answer (score 1):

$[x, y]$ here is the *super* or graded commutator (in the graded algebra of graded endomorphisms of $A$), which you may not be used to; it refers to

$$xy - (-1)^{\deg x \deg y} yx$$

and so if either $x$ or $y$ is even it reduces to the ordinary commutator but if $x, y$ are both odd it's the anticommutator; in particular $[d, d] = 2d^2$ because $d$ is odd.

I've never seen this definition before but the motivation is spelled out pretty clearly:

> "satisfying the relations of contractions, Lie derivative and differential on a manifold with a $\mathfrak{g}$-action"

presumably means this definition is intended to abstract the action of $\mathfrak{g}$ on differential forms $\Omega^{\bullet}(M)$ coming from a smooth action of a corresponding Lie group $G$ on $M$.

$L_{(-)}$ and $i_{(-)}$ are presumably also intended to be linear although this isn't stated explicitly.

Comment: I just want to confirm what you mean by action of $\mathfrak{g}$ on $\Omega^{\bullet}(M)$...  Given $A\in \mathfrak{g}$, action of $G$ on $M$ gives a vector field $A^*$ on $M$... Given a vector field $X$ on $M$ and a differential form $\omega$ on $M$, I know two ways to associate another differential form.. One way is to consider $L_X\omega$ (degree does not change in this case). another is to consider the $i_X\omega$ (degree reduce by $1$ in this case)... Is this what you are referring to as actions on $\mathfrak{g}$ on $\Omega^{\bullet}(M)$...

Comment: Yes, that’s what this definition is intended to abstract.

Comment: Thanks for confirmation... Do you happen to know any references for these... In particular, for "graded algebra of graded endomorphisms of A".. I know the definition but not much properties...